# form element width

Tags: html, css, forms

On [this page](http://upstudio.ie/donal/create.htm) the Longitude form input has a width of 181px and the Type select has a width of 175px. I can't figure out why they have different widths, because in both cases the relevant CSS rule is:

```
.uniForm .small {
    width: 30% !important;
}
```

and the parent div in both cases has a width of 604px.

Similarly, the Country select is 6px shorter than the Address text input, even though they both seem to be governed by the same CSS rules.

### Update

Thanks to the explanations about the different box-sizing models used, I added the following CSS rule, but it doesn't seem to have fixed the problem (in Firefox):

```
html {      
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -khtml-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: in all the browsers? maybe you are needing a height or a float.
".small" is a div?

Comment: .small is a CSS class that is applied to the select and input elements in the form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make sure different elements employ the same size, as specified in CSS, first make sure they're all using the same `box-sizing` model, such as:

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-o-box-sizing: border-box;
-khtml-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/JmvF5/1/).

---

**Edited** in response to question from OP, in comments below:

> Would you be able concoct some sort of rule that would ensure a consistent box sizing model is applied to all form elements?

A rule itself is easy enough to create, but it won't be implemented by *all* form elements, since `<input type="radio" />` and `<input type="checkbox" />` (at the *least*) will disregard the rules, however my best attempt, currently:

```
#formElementID input, /* note that this will include `<input type="submit" />` and so on...
#formElementID select,
#formElementID textarea {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -khtml-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

References:

- [`box-sizing` at Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Box-sizing).

Comment: Would you be able concoct some sort of rule that would ensure a consistent box sizing model is applied to all form elements? Thanks for the fiddle demo

Comment: What about `<input type="radio" />` or `<input type="checkbox" />`? I don't think you'd *want* them to use a different box-model, nor do I think they'd obey it if it was assigned...

Comment: I added the rule shown in the question update, but it didn't seem to change anything

Comment: Make sure you've not got any `!important` declarations overriding it, and ensure that the rule is sufficiently specific to override any other conflicting rules.

Comment: @Don `input, select, textarea, button, meter, output, datalist, progress { … }`

Comment: @DavidThomas [chromium's browser stylesheet](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css?rev=103468) already applies border-box to radio and input elements.

Comment: You're very welcome, and I'm glad to have been of help! =D Also: wooo..! *Prizes..!*

Answer (score 3):

The `select` element has a box-sizing of `border-box`, whereas the `input` element has that of `content-box`. This causes the calculation of width and padding to be done differently for the different elements.

This is something I consider to be a flaw in the default style sheets of various browsers. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334766/should-html-buttons-have-the-same-box-model-as-everything-else) I asked a little while ago.