# Why do HTML <buttons> adhere to the old IE5 box model in all modern browsers?

Tags: html, css

I've had a weird issue with a button and some CSS, I noticed that it was behaving as if it adhered to the old IE5 box model, where height = height + padding.

After some browsing I came across [this article](http://www.cssnewbie.com/button-height-and-a-broken-box-model/) which confirmed my assumptions but didn't explain why this is the case.

Does anybody know why ALL modern browsers (Firefox, Chrome, IE9) treat button elements like this? And does anybody know of a workaround to make button elements use the box model that (as far as I can tell) ever other element in those browsers uses?

Comment: That's the IE5 box model, not IE6. IE6 has a working, albeit slightly buggy, implementation of the standard box model which works in standards mode, whereas IE5 doesn't have one at all.

Comment: What `DOCTYPE` are you using?

Comment: Also, sorry about the IE6/5 thing, wasn't 100% sure on that. I'll edit my question

Comment: I just confirmed it with <!DOCTYPE html> and FF14, Chrome 20, Opera 12, IE9, Safari 5(PC).

Comment: Found a kind of an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334766/should-html-buttons-have-the-same-box-model-as-everything-else

Comment: Tested with both <button type="button/submit"> and <input type="button/submit"> and it's the same in all tested browsers. And <input type="text"> uses the W3C model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never even realized that buttons act this way, but I generally don't use input elements and opt to fashion div equivalents since they are far easier to style and make look the same in all browsers.

A work-around to make buttons scale like div elements could be to set the `box-sizing` attribute to `content-box`, which is the default value for divs:

```
button, input[type=button], input[type=submit]
{
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

[Here's an example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Srg4m/1/).

Comment: With `box-sizing: context-box;` it worked on IE9, Chrome 20, Opera 12 and Safari 5(pc). And by adding `-moz-box-sizing: content-box;` it also works in FF14.

Comment: Works in all of them but IE7! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

The funny thing about asking this question at this time is that several of the higher-end people in the JS/CSS community have started using the very-compatible version of this box model, in their production projects.

`box-sizing : border-box` will make most modern browsers behave like the inputs.
See: [Paul Irish - Border-Box FTW](http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)

The immediate benefit is being able to line everything up much faster, without having to play with negative margins, unless you actually intend to do z-index overlays of non-`fixed` / non-`absolute` positioned elements.

Comment: Yes, I'd heard something similar to that too, I've only recently discovered the old box model existed (IE5). And that article definitely looks interesting, will put it away for a read later!

Answer (score 0):

`<button>` is considered as an inline tag, then it naturally doesn't use the W3C box model.

This is purely logical, but I agree, totally disturbing. The point now is : why isn't it considered as a block tag ?

```css
button {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 0 30px;
}

#a { display: inline; }
#b { display: block; }
#c { display: inline; box-sizing: content-box; }
#d { display: block; box-sizing: content-box; }
```

```html
<button id="a">aaa</button> 
<button id="b">bbb</button>
<button id="c">ccc</button>
<button id="d">ddd</button>
```

Comment: Placing buttons next to each other is an extremely common design practice, so it makes sense that they default to `inline`. Yes, `inline-block` would maintain the inline nature of the element while allowing it to be styled like a block-level element, but I don't think any element defaults to `inline-block`.

Comment: I don't think a display of inline affects whether the box model is height=height or height=padding+border+height

Comment: Then again I could be totally wrong there, I'm pretty sure you guys know more about this than I do (hence the question!)

Comment: @jackwanders None have `inline-block` by default. @SeanDunwooy : it does. Set `display: block` on a `<button>` tag and you'll be able to use box model.

Comment: @samsamX I tried to set it to `display:block` but it still uses the unexpected box-model. Tested in FF14, Chrome 20, IE9, Opera 12 and Safari 5(PC).

Comment: @some Right... My mistake, sorry ! We must use `box-sizing` Here is a Jsfiddle to see it http://jsfiddle.net/samsamX/esBtD/2/

Comment: I thought `img` was `inline-block` by default. Is that incorrect?

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Inline-level boxes *do* adhere to the same W3C box model as block-level boxes. Some properties may be calculated differently, or not apply to them at all because they don't make sense (for example `width`, `height` and vertical margins), but they still use the same box model.

Comment: @Codemonkey: No, `img` is an inline-level element.

Comment: @Codemonkey No. It has `display: inline` by default. Note that IE7 doen't know `inline-block`, then I assume that it isn't a default value for any tag

Comment: Yep, box-sizing works, but doesn't work in IE7 (which to me is now the new IE6)

Comment: @samsamX: I just confirmed that `select` is `display: inline-block` by default in Chrome